# Array not sorting alphabetically with sort() or asort()

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the following array that is used to create a list of buttons. These buttons are not in alphabetical order, but I am aiming to put them alphabetically. Here is the array:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
<categories>
    <category>Landscape</category>
    <category>Wildlife</category>
    <category>Action/Sports</category>
    <category>Portrait</category>
    <category>Architectural</category>
    <category>Wedding</category>
    <category>Events</category>
    <category>Fashion</category>
    <category>Macro</category>
    <category>Family</category>
    <category>Baby</category>
    <category>Abstract</category>
    <category>Bodyscape</category>
    <category>Forced Perspective</category>
    <category>Modeling</category>
</categories>
```

Now I know how to output an array into a list of buttons and I know how to sort arrays(or so I thought). I have the code below for my output. I have tried using `sort()` and `asort()` but the output is never alphabetical, but the order does change. What might I be doing wrong?

```
$gallery_catdata = new SimpleXMLElement('xml/gallery_cat.xml', 0, true);
$arr=array();
foreach($gallery_catdata->category as $category)
{
    $arr[]=$category;
}
//print_r($arr);
/* uncomment the above line to debug */
asort($arr);
//print_r($arr);
/* uncomment the above line to debug */
foreach($arr as $categories) {       
    $category = str_replace(' ', '-', $categories);
    $category = strtolower($category);
                            echo '<button data-filter=".portfolio-filter-'.$category.'">'.$categories.'</button>';
}
```

For reference here is the `print_r($arr)` unsorted:

> Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( )
>   [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [6] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [7] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [8] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [9] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [10] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [11] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( )
>   [12] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [13] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [14] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( )
>  
>   )

Here it is using `sort()`:

> Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( )
>   [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [6] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [7] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [8] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [9] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [10] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [11] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( )
>   [12] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [13] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [14] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( )
>    )

And finally using `asort()`:

> Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [11] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( )
>    [9] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [13] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [8] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [10] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( )
>   [6] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [12] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [7] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   [14] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
>   )`

Comment: Your `asort` example appears to be working correctly; no string data is shown by the id values are mixed implying that the array is indeed sorted by some other reference - ie; by alphabetical sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which php version you are running, but I would be expecting your script to be emitting:

> Warning: sort() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Just convert your data structure from an object to an array via explicit casting.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/0AIQI))

```
$xml = <<<XML
<categories>
    <category>Landscape</category>
    <category>Wildlife</category>
    <category>Action/Sports</category>
    <category>Portrait</category>
    <category>Architectural</category>
    <category>Wedding</category>
    <category>Events</category>
    <category>Fashion</category>
    <category>Macro</category>
    <category>Family</category>
    <category>Baby</category>
    <category>Abstract</category>
    <category>Bodyscape</category>
    <category>Forced Perspective</category>
    <category>Modeling</category>
</categories>
XML;

$categories = (array)simplexml_load_string($xml, 'SimpleXMLElement')->category;

sort($categories);

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo $category , "\n";
}
```